# Python WKT or Proj4 lookup package

Tags: python, software-recommendations, proj, well-known-text, utm

I am looking for a Python package that would allow me to input a UTM zone code and output different geo_referencing strings (for example, WKT or Proj4). Are there any lightweight, widely used packages out there that perform this function?

Comment: GDAL is big but with it you can do this http://www.gdal.org/gdalsrsinfo.html. Study the source code and think how much of GDAL and Proj4 you really need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the **Python bindings for GDAL and OGR**. If GDAL/OGR is installed on our machine, the `pcs.csv` file in `gdal-data` directory contains an extract of the EPSG Registry about projected coordinate reference systems, so we can filter this file to obtain the result. Suppose we are interested in zone 33, here's a quick and dirty solution:

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr

in_ds = ogr.GetDriverByName('CSV').Open('pcs.csv')
layer = in_ds.GetLayer()
zone = '33' #'33N'
layer.SetAttributeFilter("COORD_REF_SYS_NAME LIKE '%UTM zone {0}%'".format(zone))
for feature in layer:
    code = feature.GetField("COORD_REF_SYS_CODE")
    name = feature.GetField("COORD_REF_SYS_NAME")
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.ImportFromEPSG(int(code))
    print 'EPSG:' + code + ' - ' + name
    print 'Proj4: ', srs.ExportToProj4()
    print 'WKT: ', srs.ExportToWkt()
    print
```

**Note:** we can refine the search choosing also the hemisphere (e.g. 33N) changing the value of the `zone` variable in the code.

This is an extract of the result:

```
EPSG:2078 - ELD79 / UTM zone 33N
Proj4:  +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-115.8543,-99.0583,-152.4616,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
WKT:  PROJCS["ELD79 / UTM zone 33N",GEOGCS["ELD79",DATUM["European_Libyan_Datum_1979",SPHEROID["International 1924",6378388,297,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7022"]],TOWGS84[-115.8543,-99.0583,-152.4616,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6159"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4159"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","2078"]]

EPSG:2312 - Garoua / UTM zone 33N
Proj4:  +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=clrk80 +units=m +no_defs 
WKT:  PROJCS["Garoua / UTM zone 33N",GEOGCS["Garoua",DATUM["Garoua",SPHEROID["Clarke 1880 (RGS)",6378249.145,293.465,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7012"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6197"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4197"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","2312"]]

EPSG:2313 - Kousseri / UTM zone 33N
Proj4:  +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=clrk80 +units=m +no_defs 
WKT:  PROJCS["Kousseri / UTM zone 33N",GEOGCS["Kousseri",DATUM["Kousseri",SPHEROID["Clarke 1880 (RGS)",6378249.145,293.465,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7012"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6198"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4198"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","2313"]]
```

Comment: I am having trouble, using your above code I get the error:"'NoneType' 'object has no attribute 'GetLayer' 'getting thrown on: ' layer = in_ds.GetLayer(). Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the 3rd row of the script: the `pcs.csv` file should be in the same directory where the script is located or alternatively type there its original path.

Answer (score 3):

GDAL contains the most complete open source implementation and I'm not aware of any port to Python.

[Rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) does the same kind of thing as GDAL's Python bindings and calls the same C library functions.

```
>>> from rasterio.crs import CRS
>>> CRS.from_epsg(4326).wkt
'GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

Rasterio is not lightweight by any measure.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below:-

https://github.com/cmollet/sridentify
..............

Answer (score 0):

https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/examples.html

```py
>>> from pyproj import CRS
>>> crs = CRS("WGS 84 / UTM Zone 14N")
>>> crs.to_proj4()
<stdin>:1: UserWarning: You will likely lose important projection information when converting to a PROJ string from another format. See: https://proj.org/faq.html#what-is-the-best-format-for-describing-coordinate-reference-systems
'+proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs'
>>> crs.to_epsg()
32614
>>> print(crs.to_wkt(pretty=True))
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 14N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 14N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-99,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Engineering survey, topographic mapping."],
        AREA["Between 102°W and 96°W, northern hemisphere between equator and 84°N, onshore and offshore. Canada - Manitoba; Nunavut; Saskatchewan. Mexico. United States (USA)."],
        BBOX[0,-102,84,-96]],
    ID["EPSG",32614]]
```